# Using python to connect to Docebo api via Oauth2

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0

This is what I have so far. No real success. Trying to retrieve a token, but nothing seems to work. Just returns a giant mess of characters.

```
import requests
import json

auth_url = "http://learn.ZZZZZZZ.com/oauth2/authorize"

#credential
auth_client_id = "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
auth_client_secret = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"  

payload={'grant_type':'client_credentials', 'client_id':auth_client_id,'client_secret':auth_client_secret}
headers={'Accept':'application/json', 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

response = requests.post(auth_url,headers=headers,data=payload)
response.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the token endpoint to obtain an access token.
`auth_url = "http://learn.ZZZZZZZ.com/oauth2/token"`

[Docebo API documentation](https://www.docebo.com/lms-docebo-api-third-party-integration/)